# What are the pros/cons of 'bsub < script.sh'

Tags: scheduler, job-scheduling, lsf

Consider first `script_0.sh`:

```
# script_0.sh

foo
bar
baz
```

I can run this script via LSF like this, for example:

```
bsub -q myqueue -J myjob_0 -o path/to/log_0.out -e path/to/log_0.err -- /bin/sh ./script_0.sh
```

Now consider a second, very similar script:

```
# script_1.sh

#BSUB -q myqueue
#BSUB -J myjob_1
#BSUB -o path/to/log_1.out
#BSUB -e path/to/log_1.err

foo
bar
baz
```

I can also run this script, via LSF, as shown above (after changing the command-line options appropriately), but, *in addition*, I can do it like this:

```
bsub < script_1.sh
```

In this second form, `bsub` figures out the options to use by parsing the lines beginning with `#BSUB` .

As far as I understand, all the forms described above would entail running exactly the same commands (`foo`, etc.), since the two scripts are identical, if we exclude comments and blank lines.

What are the pros/cons of this second form vis-à-vis the first form?  In particular, does either form make possible job scheduling strategies that are difficult or impossible to implement with the other form?